# Simplify s.charAt from 'a' || 'b' || 'c' || to one s.charAt

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop

I am making a letter counting program. Instead of using 26 cases, is there a way to use one case to increase the count of letters in a string. Is it possible to simplify this program?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CountLetters
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      {
      String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any text.");
      int count = 0;
      String s = str.toLowerCase(); 
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
          if (s.charAt(i)==('a')||s.charAt(i)=='b'||s.charAt(i)=='c'||s.charAt(i)=='d'||s.charAt(i)=='e'||s.charAt(i)=='f'||
        s.charAt(i)=='g'||s.charAt(i)=='h'||s.charAt(i)=='i'||s.charAt(i)=='j'||s.charAt(i)=='k'||s.charAt(i)=='l'||
        s.charAt(i)=='m'||s.charAt(i)=='n'||s.charAt(i)=='o'||s.charAt(i)=='p'||s.charAt(i)=='q'||s.charAt(i)=='r'||
        s.charAt(i)=='s'||s.charAt(i)=='t'||s.charAt(i)=='u'||s.charAt(i)=='v'||s.charAt(i)=='w'||s.charAt(i)=='x'||
        s.charAt(i)=='y'||s.charAt(i)=='z') {
        count++;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("There are " + count + " letters in the string you entered.");
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this program so there would be only one if condition, not 26?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the greater than and less than operators:

```
if (s.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s.charAt(i) <= 'z')
```

Comment: Depending on whether high-Unicode lowercase is acceptable, `Character.isLowerCase()` might be more readable.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need a loop.

```
int count = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","").length();
System.out.println("There are " + count + " letters in the string you entered.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's Character class:

```
public String numLetters(String str){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This is really close except it would also match uppercase.

Comment: Yes, so instead of using Character.isLetter(char), you can use Character.isLowerCase(char) instead if you only want to count the lower case letters

Comment: Soooo ... edit your answer ;) His code is only counting lowercase.

Comment: I think he is counting the number of letters, not just lower case letters. The reason why he converts it to lower case is so he could use those 26 different cases. If he did not convert it to lower case, then he would end up with 52 different cases, which would be a pain to type out.

Comment: Yeah - I totally skipped over where he'd called `toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using `char` altogether and use `substring()` with a regex via `matches()`

```
if (s.substring(i, i+1).matches("[a-z]"))
```

(Yes, `(i, i+1)` ... the end index is exclusive)

**Edit to add:** In thinking about it,

```
if(Character.isLowerCase(s.chatAt(i))
```

is probably better. Ignoring any performance implications with using a regex, this is *the easiest to read*; someone looking at it instantly understands the intent.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Your use of `matches` is wrong anyway.  `matches` returns `true` only if the entire string matches the pattern, so this would work only if `s` were exactly one character long.  (And the 1-arg version of `substring` won't help either.)  Note that using `^` at the beginning of a pattern, when using `s.matches`, is redundant.

Comment: @ajb Whoops, gah, my mind is set to Ruby regexes since I've been programming in it so much lately :P sorry, I'll delete my comments

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow You had me double-checking my sanity for a moment :-)